# How to match numbers separated by whitespace till end of the line?

Tags: java, regex

I want to take in an input of numbers each followed by a whitespace till the end of the line . I want to take in all these numbers and store it in an array. How can i accomplish this using Regular Expressions?

**Input: 4 5 6 7 9 8**

**Output: arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]**

```
String list = scan.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Regex);
String[] matchRegex = pattern.split(list);
```

Comment: I just started learning regex so i wanted to try it out.I could alternatively use split to strore it in an array of strings and loop through it and do Integer prarsing. @KhalilM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Regex` needs to match the separator-symbol. You use a whitespace as separator so you can simply use a whitespace as Regex. The code then looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
String[] matchRegex = pattern.split(list);
```

You can also use the whitespace-group if you want to also match other whitespace characters, it is `\s`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
```

If there can be multiple whitespaces you can extend the `Regex` by using `+`, it matches "*at least one up to indefinitely many*".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
```

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test your `Regex` against input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split with space like :

```
String[] matchRegex = list.split("\\s+");
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mSM0S/1)